# No background data on Gingerbread

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, background-data

When I launch GooglePlay, I get kicked out with error "`Background data disabled` / `Google Play Store needs background data to be enabled`". The official help page (https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1663315?hl=en) seems to be for newer OS versions, because I don't have such options in settings menu.

My Android version is Gingerbread 2.3.6

I haven't used GooglePlay in long time, I am not sure what changed/updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the settings under "Accounts and Sync" category.

Comment: @benjaminS You have to wait two days before accepting your own answer. Just have patience!